# Need sample program for FIX parser

Tags: quickfixj

I have to write a Java program. I need to parse a FIX format content. I saw so many links on google/stackoverflow for parsing FIX message. But all of them were using quickfix/J or there were some Java programs but they were reading a particular type of FIX message.

Can you please help me in parsing my FIX content in a simple way in Java.

Content:

> 8=FIX.4.4_9=1439_35=R_34=159_49=SENDERCOMPID1_52=20131216-13:37:16.302_56=WFS_XYZ_TEST_12345_DLRDPL_131=TRD_20131216_WFS_TRSY_1_4_1_146=1_55=[N/A]_60=20131216-13:37:16_75=20131216_464=Y_5745=1_828=57_5766=BMKSWITCH_453=3_448=wfscust13_447=C_452=3_802=4_523=Well
>   Customer13_803=2_523=NY_803=25_523=US_803=4000_523=94039005_803=4001_448=Wells
>   Fargo Test
>   Customer_447=C_452=1_802=2_523=DJ10_803=4002_523=NO_803=4003_448=Bilateral_447=C_452=4_555=2_600=
>   1     11/30/19
>   7yr_602=912828UB4_603=1_607=6_609=TNOTE_611=20191130_249=20121130_615=1_624=1_556=USD_588=20121220_686=1_685=25720000_824=TRD_TRSY_1_566=98.484375_600=7
>   Yr vs 3M
>   LIBOR_602=RU00007YL3MS_603=8_607=12_609=IRSUSD_764=BMK_611=20191221_624=P_556=USD_588=20121221_677=LIBOR_678=3M_686=6_685=25000000_824=TRD_XYZ_1_566=1.32581_539=1_524=Bilateral_525=C_538=4_10=141

Comment: Pay someone... So far there is no coding question in your post.

Comment: Alexei, I need some pointers so that I can parse my above given content to XML file. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickfixJ is the way to go. This will give you flexibility to parse any FIX message and will support messages with repeating groups. If you're set on just using Java to parse the FIX, bear in mind it's hard to parse messages that might contain repeating groups.

You just need to extend QuickfixJ's MessageCracker class.

http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.3/usage/receiving_messages.html

Comment: if you want an online tool you could use https://fixparser.chronicle.software it allows you to parse the fix messages and then extract then as JSON